# Issue with ui-view scroll offset

Tags: angularjs, uiview, ui-sref

I have a scrolling problem regarding my ui-sref elements.

index.html looks like this:

```
<header>
<div id="header" class="flat-menu single-menu" ng-include="'partials/header-hr.html'"></div>
</header>
<div ui-view></div>
<footer id="footer" data-ng-include="'partials/footer-hr.html'"></footer>
```

The header part of the dropdown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a ui-sref="about({ '#': 'a' })"">a</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="about({ '#': 'b' })"">b</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="about({ '#': 'c' })"">c</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="about({ '#': 'd' })"">d</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="about({ '#': 'e' })"">e</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, scrolling to a particular ui-sref works, but it positions the view to the top of the page (behind the header) and you're unable to see first few rows.

Is there any way to offset uiviewscroll so that the sref starts below the header?

P.s. this is my first post here so forgive me if I failed to provide the whole context needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your header overlapping your content, right.

What you need to do is.

*Add this CSS property in your header:*

**position: relative;**

OR

This is another solution - use your ui-sref outside your header div like this:

```
<header>
   <div id="header" class="flat-menu single-menu" ng-include="'partials/header-hr.html'"></div>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a ui-sref="about({ '#': 'a' })"">a</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="about({ '#': 'b' })"">b</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="about({ '#': 'c' })"">c</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="about({ '#': 'd' })"">d</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="about({ '#': 'e' })"">e</a></li>
   </ul>
</header>
<div ui-view></div>
<footer id="footer" data-ng-include="'partials/footer-hr.html'"></footer>
```

Comment: i guess i've written it kinda hard to understand...
first of all, <ul> elements are a part of the separate header.html.
second, links are open in a new tab.

i've tried the position solution, but it didn't work :(